# Se puede cambiar el color de "una linea del JTextArea"?

Tags: java

Consulta, se puede cambiar el color de una sola línea que se imprime en un JTextArea? digo, porque estoy usando **JTextArea.setForeground(Color.green)** y me cambia el color de todas las lineas, mi idea es que la que sea correcta la imprima en verde, y la incorrecta en rojo. Lo vengo haciendo, pero cuando entra en ejecución me cambia el color de todas las lineas.

```
botonvel1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        Object obj= e.getSource();
        if(obj.equals(botonvel1))
        { 
            if(Integer.parseInt(textfieldvel1.getText())<=250)
            {
            System.out.println("bien");
            enunciado.setForeground(Color.green);
            enunciado.append("\n- Velocidad mínima correcta - Esa velocidad puede andar dependiendo de los grados de elevación.\n");
            }
            else{System.out.println("mal");
            enunciado.setForeground(Color.red);
            enunciado.append("- Velocidad mínima incorrecta - Esa velocidad es muy alta para ser mínima.\n");
            }
        }

    }});

botonvel2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        Object obj= e.getSource();
        if(obj.equals(botonvel2))
        { 
            if(Integer.parseInt(textfieldvel2.getText())<=450)
            {
            System.out.println("bien");
            enunciado.setForeground(Color.green);
            enunciado.append("\n- Velocidad máxima correcta - A esa velocidad probablemente no se dañen los trenes de aterrizaje.\n");
            }
            else{System.out.println("mal");
            enunciado.setForeground(Color.red);
            enunciado.append("- Velocidad máxima incorrecta - Seguramente los trenes no soporten las abraciones del viento.\n");
            }
        }

    }});


botondist1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        Object obj= e.getSource();
        if(obj.equals(botondist1))
        { 
            if(Integer.parseInt(textfielddist1.getText())>=2000)
            {
            System.out.println("bien");
            enunciado.setForeground(Color.green);
            enunciado.append("\n- Distancia mínima correcta - Esa distancia alcanza para que pueda despegar en mínima velocidad.\n");
            }
            else{System.out.println("mal");
            enunciado.setForeground(Color.red);
            enunciado.append("- Distancia máxima incorrecta - Esa distancia no alcanza para despegar a velocidad mínima.\n");
            }
        }

    }});


botondist2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        Object obj= e.getSource();
        if(obj.equals(botondist2))
        { 
            if(Integer.parseInt(textfielddist2.getText())>=2000)
            {
            System.out.println("bien");
            enunciado.setForeground(Color.green);
            enunciado.append("\n- Distancia mínima correcta -\n");
            }
            else{System.out.println("mal");
            enunciado.setForeground(Color.red);
            enunciado.append("- Distancia máxima incorrecta -\n");
            }
        }

    }});
```

Comment: Intenté crear un label de variable y adherirlo al JTextArea, y no anduvo, una pena.

Comment: Te doy una respuesta con Codigo Fuente incluido que fue buscada (espero entiendas el codigo interno, te sirva de algo y dale los creditos a esa persona que se molesto en publicarlo en esa pagina :3), cuando pueda, con gusto intentare con esa pequeña respuesta ver si puedo ayudarte :D : http://www.myjavazone.com/2011/10/texto-con-colores-en-un-jtextpane.html